# Twig indexpage add numeric in one single category

Tags: twig

On a SaaS platform I try to create an indexpage/sitemap for a website with a lot of categories.
**Since it's a SaaS platform I'm not able to use/create custom functions whatsoever.** 
It have to be done at the frontend.

What I try to do is divide a list of categories into a list divided in letters and digits. 
So a category name starting with A will go in category "A", a category starting with a number (eg 18 years) will go in a category called "0-9". So I will get an indexpage like so:

```
[A]
- Alpha
- Anton
- etc..

[B]
- Beta
- Brave
- etc..

[C]
- Charlie
- Cooking
- etc..

[0-9]
- 1 year
- 20 years
- 99 years
- etc..
```

I managed to get this working for all letters. However it not always put numbers in the [0-9] category. My script sometimes create a seperate index for eg 0 or 7 etc. So like:

```
[0]
- 1 year
- 18 years
- etc..

[1]
- 2 years
- 22 years
```

Also the index number is wrong. So it shows 1 under 0 and 2 under 1. Instead of:

```
[0-9]
- 1 year
- 18 years
- 2 years
- 22 years
```

I just can't see why that is. So my question is how can I put [numeric] categories in a single categorie called [0-9] instead of having them in a seperate categorie?

My code upto now looks like (some filters are specific platform filters):

```
{# ---------------- BEGINING ------------------- #}
{% set all_categories = [] %}
{% for category in shop.categories  %}
  {% set all_categories = all_categories | merge({ (0): category }) %}
    {% for sub in category.subs  %}
        {% set all_categories = all_categories | merge({ (0): sub }) %}
    {% for sub_sub in sub.subs  %}
        {% set all_categories = all_categories | merge({ (0): sub_sub }) %}
                {% for sub_sub_sub in sub_sub.subs  %}
            {% set all_categories = all_categories | merge({ (0): sub_sub_sub }) %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}


{% set categories = all_categories %}

{# ---------------- SORT LOGIC ------------------- #}
{# 'categories' array will be sorted and saved as 'grouped_categories' variable #}

{% set sorted_categories = [] %}
{% for key in categories | keys %}
  {% set sorted_categories = sorted_categories | merge({ (key): categories[key].title }) %}
{% endfor %}
{% set sorted_categories = sorted_categories | sort %}

{% set first_letter = '' %}
{% set grouped_categories = [] %}
{% set new_group = [] %}

{% for i in sorted_categories  | keys %}
    {% if(categories[i].title) %}
        {% set currect_first_letter = categories[i].title | first | upper %}
        {% if(currect_first_letter != first_letter) %}
            {% if(new_group) %}
                {% set grouped_categories = grouped_categories | merge({ (first_letter): new_group }) %}
            {% endif %}
            {% set first_letter = currect_first_letter %}
            {% set new_group = [categories[i]] %}
        {% else %}
            {% set new_group = new_group | merge({ (0): categories[i] }) %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% set grouped_categories = grouped_categories | merge({ (first_letter): new_group }) %}

{# ---------------- USING ------------------- #}

    <div class="single-letter">
      <span class="custom-title">{{ "All themes"  }}:</span>
      <ul>
      {% for letter in grouped_categories[1:] | keys %}
        <li><a href="#letter-{{ letter}}">{{ letter }}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
      {% for letter in grouped_categories[:1] | keys %}
        <li><a href="#letter-{{ letter}}">{{ '0-9' }}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </div>

    {% for letter in grouped_categories[1:] | keys %}
    <div id="letter-{{letter}}" class="letter-wrap">
      <h3 class="title">{{ letter }}</h3>
      <div class="group">
        <ul>
        {% for category in grouped_categories[letter] %}
          <li><a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}

        {% for letter in grouped_categories[:1] | keys %}
    <div id="letter-{{letter}}" class="letter-wrap">
      <h3 class="title">{{ '0-9' }}</h3>
      <div class="group">
        <ul>
        {% for category in grouped_categories[letter] %}
          <li><a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}


{# ---------------- THE END ------------------- #}
```

**UPDATE AS PER REQUEST**

Updated code

```
    {% for category in categories %}
        {% set currect_first_letter = category | first | upper %}
        {% if currect_first_letter in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] %}
            {% set currect_first_letter = '0-9' %}
        {% endif %}

        {% if not (currect_first_letter in (grouped_categories | keys)) %}
            {% set grouped_categories = grouped_categories | merge({ (currect_first_letter): [], }) %}
        {% endif %}
        {% set grouped_categories = grouped_categories | merge({ (currect_first_letter) : grouped_categories[currect_first_letter] | merge([ category, ]), }) %}
    {% endfor %}

{#{% set sorted_categories = [] %}
{% for key in categories | keys %}
  {% set sorted_categories = sorted_categories | merge({ (key): categories[key].title }) %}
{% endfor %}
{% set sorted_categories = sorted_categories | sort %}

{% set first_letter = '' %}
{% set grouped_categories = [] %}
{% set new_group = [] %}
{% for i in sorted_categories  | keys %}
    {% if(categories[i].title) %}
        {% set currect_first_letter = categories[i].title | first | upper %}

        {% if(currect_first_letter != first_letter) %}
            {% if(new_group) %}
                {% set grouped_categories = grouped_categories | merge({ (first_letter): new_group }) %}
            {% endif %}
            {% set first_letter = currect_first_letter %}
            {% set new_group = [categories[i]] %}

        {% else %}
            {% set new_group = new_group | merge({ (0): categories[i] }) %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% set grouped_categories = grouped_categories | merge({ (first_letter): new_group }) %}#}
```

This has as result:

```
The merge filter only works with arrays or hashes; NULL and array given in....
```

Comment: You can simply check if character is number with {% if letter|number_format == letter %}{# do your stuff #}{% endif %}. With this you should be able to put categories starting with number into one array. Are you looking for this?

Comment: @fbuchlak: I guess so :) Do you mind to give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to solve this if you override the `currect_first_letter`.

```html
{% set currect_first_letter = categories[i].title | first | upper %}
{% if currect_first_letter in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 , 9, ] %}
    {% set currect_first_letter = '0-9' %} {# change to same group #}
{% endif %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/otwdeh)

---

Okay I've gone over your code and simplified the grouping process a bit.
Here is the code I would use to combine arrays in twig

```html
{% set grouped_categories = [] %}

{% for category in categories %}
        {% set currect_first_letter = category | first | upper %}

        {# ----- ADDED THIS LINE ------- #}
        {% if currect_first_letter in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] %}
            {% set currect_first_letter = '0-9' %}
        {% endif %}
        {# ----------------------------- #}
        {% if not (currect_first_letter in (grouped_categories | keys)) %}
            {% set grouped_categories = grouped_categories | merge({ (currect_first_letter): [], }) %}
        {% endif %}
        {% set grouped_categories = grouped_categories | merge({ (currect_first_letter) : grouped_categories[currect_first_letter] | merge([ category, ]), }) %}
{% endfor %}
```

Validation purpose:

```html
{% for key in grouped_categories|keys %}
    Key: {{ key }}
    Values: 
            {% for value in grouped_categories[key] %}
                - {{ value }}

            {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/thjgdj)

---

It seems if you use `var in [0, 1, ...]`, before `twig 3.X` the `0` will return a false positive.

Try to use your original code,  the one where everything got grouped in [0-9], but with the following statement

```html
{% if currect_first_letter in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] or currect_first_letter == '0' %}
```

Comment: I get the idea but I just tried this and this puts all categories under `0-9`, so also categories starting with 'A', 'B' etc.... Any idea why that is?

Comment: Please update the question with the modified code. Should work, see [here](https://twigfiddle.com/otwdeh/2)

Comment: I'm sorry but I feel incredibly stupid. I get an error now as you can see in my updated question. I've uncommented the sort logic and used your code in place of that. I'm probably looking at this way too long now but I just can't see anything what's wrong. Your demo is working exactly as should but I can't get it to work in my code :(

Comment: Which twig version are you using btw?

Comment: Ohh man I have no idea. It's a SaaS platform so my best guess would be v1 or v2. At least not the latest version (v3).

Comment: Ohh man you're a true Twig wizard :) It works now... This immediately explains why category names with "16 years" where stored in `[0]` and not in `[1]`. Awesome!!